# Strategy for mapping locally created core data objects to webserver and back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, core-data, mapping

I'm trying to devise a solution to use across many models for mapping locally created nested relationships to the server and back. Consider that I have the following models:

`Order
LineItem
Payment`

An `Order` has many line items and payments.

If I create an order locally, send it to server, I can map the `id` attribute assigned by the server no problem, as I am working on the same object. However, my dilemma revolves around submitting nested attributes to the server. Consider this:

I create an `Order` and `Payment` locally, and send to the server's REST endpoint for `Order`

`{"email":"test@gmail.com", payments_attributes: [{"amount": 15.50}, {"amount": 12}]}`

And I receive a JSON response with something like:

`{"id": 10, "email":"test@gmail.com", payments_attributes: [{"id": 50, "amount": 15.50}, {"id": 51, "amount": 12}}`

What's a good strategy for mapping these nested payment `id` attributes back to the correct Core Data object? I can obviously check things like payment amount, but thats brittle (imagine the edge cases!), and works only for the payment model. I need a generalized solution to use for many different models. The only thing I can think of is to create a `UUID` locally, send it up, and have the server push it back along with the `id`, but that requires a lot of patching on the server side and I hate the idea of the client managing unique attributes. My backend is Rails and I want this working with minimal (if any) changes to the server side.

I've been previously using RestKit, and it magically worked (I think it nuked the local objects and created new ones) but I am working towards dropping that dependency and doing the mapping myself... for performance and control reasons.

Comment: Why store them in core data before you have confirmation from the server?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you already know what you need to do.

With the current server API, you can only match up data by looking at values. Since they're not guaranteed to be unique, the results of matching them are not guaranteed to be reliable.

If you send some unique ID to the server, which returns it, then you have a unique key that unambiguously matches your outgoing data to the new incoming data. The server doesn't need to store this ID or do anything else with it-- it just needs to make sure to take the incoming ID and include it with the outgoing result data. It doesn't even matter if multiple clients have the same unique IDs, since all they're doing with them is matching outgoing server data to returned data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I've come up with.

**Server Modifications**

- Add a Ruby Mixin to all `ActiveRecord::Base` classes that will utilize this
- Create a reusable base template for rendering JSON

Mixin

```
module CoreDataIdentification
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    attr_accessor :object_id
  end
end
```

And to use it:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  include CoreDataIdentification
end
```

Or simply (in an initializer):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, CoreDataIdentification
```

Easy enough! This works well, because the ID is not persisted to the server database, it simply passes back whatever it was given.

JSON Template (using the RABL gem)

```
attributes :id
attributes :object_id, if: lambda {|object| object&.object_id }
node(:errors) { |object| object.errors }
node(:created_at) {|object| object.api_timestamp(:created_at) }
node(:deleted_at) {|object| object.api_timestamp(:deleted_at) }
node(:updated_at) {|object| object.api_timestamp(:updated_at) } if locals[:index]
node(:errors) { |object| object.errors } if locals[:errors]
```

Example `order.rabl`

```
object @line_item
extends('base', locals: {index: locals[:index], errors: locals[:errors]})
attributes :order_id, :price, :adjustment_total, :promo_total, :additional_tax_total, :included_tax_total, :additional_service_fee_total, :included_service_fee_total, :quantity, :variant_id, :currency, :pre_tax_amount
```

Client side code (Objective-C)

- Subclass NSManagedObject to serve as a template for managing commonly shared attributes between all models (`id`, `object_id`, `created_at`, etc)
- Method: Serialize core data attributes to JSON
- Method: Map JSON attributes to Core Data
- Method: Map JSON relationships to Core Data

Some sample code that I am still playing with:

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)requestParams
{
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    if (self.id)
        params[@"id"] = self.id;
    else {

        params[@"object_id"] = self.objectID.URIRepresentation.absoluteString;

    }

    return params;
}
```

And to map the relationships:

```
- (void)mapRelationships:(NSDictionary *)JSON
{
    [self connectKeyPath:@"line_items" dict:JSON entity:@"LineItem"];
    [self connectKeyPath:@"payments" dict:JSON entity:@"Payment"];
    //[self connectKeyPath:@"adjustments" dict:JSON entity:@"Adjustment"];

}



+ (GMManagedObject *)objectFromURL:(NSString *)URL inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
    NSManagedObjectID *objectID = [[GListManager shared].managedObjectStore.persistentStoreCoordinator managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:url];
    return [context objectWithID:objectID];
}

- (void)connectKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath dict:(NSDictionary *)JSON entity:(NSString *)entityName
{
    NSArray *items = [JSON objectForKey:keyPath];

    for (NSDictionary *item_attributes in items) {

        NSString *object_id = [item_attributes objectForKey:@"object_id"];
        NSNumber *id = [item_attributes objectForKey:@"id"];

        GMManagedObject *item;

        if (object_id) {
            // find local
            item = [self.class objectFromURL:object_id inContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        } else {
            item = [self findOrCreateByEntity:entityName andId:id];
        }

        [item mapResponse:item_attributes];

    }
}
```

I still have a lot of work to do in refactoring this for flexibility and performance... but I think this is a step in the right direction... rendering thousands of lines of RestKit code moot.